# `channelAdded` event from `twilio-chat`

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm currently upgrading my implementation that uses Twilio IPM to use the new GA release `twilio-chat` after previously using the `twilio-ip-messaging` package on npm. There are some disparities between the implementations, but this hasn't really been that much of an issue so far. However it seems that there are some event behaviours that have changed and I struggle to understand why.

Prior to `twilio-chat`, if I had a client A connected in a browser context, any public channel creation (from another client B, or the server side) would trigger the `channelAdded` event from twilio. This no longer seems to happen. The new channel is visible on any subsequent `getPublicChannelDescriptors` call, but I do not receive the event.

Is it possible to opt-in to these events? Or in some other way configure that this should be announced to all connected clients?

I can think of a few workarounds, like a named persistent channel where new channel creation is announced, or some other 'push' mechanism for client A to then refresh its channels list, but all feels a bit dirty when there is already a push mechanism in place that *used* to effect the same behaviour.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'm investigating this internally, will let you know what I find out.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The `channelAdded` event for public channels was removed in the Programmable Chat SDKs because of a limitations of how many endpoints can subscribe to a single, global `public channels` object.

You can [receive these events by webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/webhooks) but you would still need a way to notify the client side of your application. Your suggestion of a persistent channel for this is a good workaround. You could even keep this channel hidden from view and send structured data in the message that would allow you to show the new channel in your interface and request more data about it via the SDK.

If a whole chat channel is too much of a hack, you could also try using [Twilio Sync to synchronise a list](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sync/sync-lists) of active channels between users.

I agree that this does seem like a bit of a hack though. It is possible that all channels will cause the `channelAdded` event again in the future, but I can't promise anything like that right now, so you will need to workaround it.